# What does "даже" mean?

Tags: перевод

The Wiktionary entry says it means "even", but the English word "even" has many different definitions. I presume the Wiktionary translation is saying that it has the adverb-emphasizer meaning, as in "He hadn't even started to run." or "Do you even understand?". Is this correct? Are there other meanings/translations of даже?

Comment: **Do you even understand?** into Russian isn't translated with **даже**, because it's an interrogative sentence, in the other, positive, sentence their use in both languages is identical

Comment: Have you ever tried to use dictionaries which are better than Wiktionary? For example, [multitran.com](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=даже) or [OpenRussian.org](https://en.openrussian.org/ru/даже).

Comment: @YellowSky I actually hadn't because up till now Wiktionary had seemed superior. Thanks for those suggestions, they seem great!

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not that easy to discuss such things as `meanings/translations/definitions` because 1) these three terms mean very different things; 2) people tend to confuse them in all possible sorts of ways.

One of the respected [Russian vocabularies](http://ozhegov.info/slovar/?ex=Y&q=%D0%94%D0%90%D0%96%D0%95) gives the following definitions to *ДАЖЕ* (but this is all in Russian, of course):

> ```
> ДАЖЕ
> ```
>
> 1. частица. Употр. при сообщении о том, что противоречит ожидаемому, осуществляется вопреки ему.  Шум не смолкает д. ночью. Все притихли,
>   д. дети. Очаровательна д. без всяких украшений.
>
> 2. частица. Употр. при сообщении о том, что осуждается как противоречащее узусу.  Д. матери грубит. Обидит д. ребенка. Не подаст
>      д. куска хлеба.
> 3. частица. Употр. для выделения той части сообщения, к-рая его подтверждает,  приводя дополнительные аргументы или еще более вескую
>      информацию.  Умен, д. талантлив. Холодно, д., кажется, снег идет.
>      Мила, д. красива.
> 4. частица. Употр. для выражения неожиданности и интенсивности того действия, о к-ром сообщается.  Д. заплакал ото радости. Обиделась, д.
>      слушать не хочет.
> 5. союз. Присоединяет предложение или член предложения со знач. уточнения, добавления.  Ветер сильный, д. провода гудят.

A simplified explanation that covers most typical patterns of usage (`meanings`) may look something along these lines ([Source](https://dictionary.reverso.net/russian-english/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5)):

> так испугался, даже вскрикнул    *I was so frightened, I even screamed*
>
> даже я согласился                *even I agreed*

`Translations`, though, is a completely different beast. And is just too large a topic, so I simply won't go into this as this would require a hell of a lot of time. Suffice to say, as an example, that your "He hadn't even started to run." would be translated with the use of `даже`, while the "Do you even understand?" will be `Ты хотя бы понимаешь?`/ `Да ты хоть понимаешь?` (or similar, depends on the context).

Answer (score 2):

The word "даже" means that an unexpected, controversial event has occured.

> "John hates popular music, but **even** he liked the latest Rihanna's
> single"
>
> "Джон ненавидит поп-музыку, но **даже** ему понравился последний сингл
> Рианны"
>
> "There was a military parade in the downtown. The orchestra played so
> loud, I could hear the music **even** outside of the city"
>
> "В центре прошёл военный парад. Оркестр играл так громко, что я слышал
> музыку **даже** за пределами города"

So, the word "даже" is similar only to this meaning of 'even".

Comment: This is only one of its *meanings*, listed under 4. in my answer. There are others, so your first sentence is not quite correct (too restrictive).