# Мeanings of "даже" in The Brothers Karamazov

Tags: словоупотребление

Here's a passage from The Brothers Karamazov:

> Несмотря на то что семейство даже довольно скоро примирилось с событием

Pevear translates: 'though her family EVEN accepted the situation', while Terras says 'Although the family ACTUALLY accepted the event'.

Which is more accurate: ACTUALLY or EVEN?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please give a link to the earlier thread and add the relevant information from the thread to your question? Thanks!

Comment: I can't imagine how I could be any more specific: I quoted the exact text of 2 versions of a translation that I am trying to choose between!
I already included the relevant information from earlier thread, but here it is: 
https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/20450/what-does-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5-mean#new-answer?newreg=cb00298225ae4ce894e49fbae10c8d12

Comment: @BillRandolph: please include the phrase you're trying to translate. It's impossible to tell which translation is more accurate without seeing the original. Thank you!

Comment: While it might seem like bad form to expect others to look up the original, maybe OP is not able to do this. Since I'm feeling generous: Несмотря на то что семейство даже довольно скоро примирилось с событием is corresponding phrase.

Comment: @Passerby: thank you!

Comment: even rather quickly

Comment: Actually is the correct translation in this case.

Comment: I agree with ACTUALLY in that context.

Answer (score 2):

The set phrases *очень даже* and *довольно даже* convey the element of contradicting expectations, similar to the English word "too":

> — Вы же ее не продаете. ― А вот и не угадали. Очень даже продаю // "But you're not selling it." "You guessed wrong. I am *too* selling it".
>
> ― Тебе, может, и не праздник, а я очень даже рад, что ты на свет появилась. // "It might not be a special day for you, but I'm actually (quite) glad you came into this world"

> Ведь и он, как другие, постоял, постоял да и пошел ― и довольно даже свободно вошел… // But he, like the others, stood there for some time and then just went — and entered quite freely, too.
>
> — Безобразенъ? — Нѣтъ, нельзя сказать, довольно даже интересенъ. // Is he ugly? No, you can't say that, he's actually quite personable.

The phrase *довольно даже* has fallen out of usage in the last hundred years, and additionally, Dostoyevsky reversed the word order. But it's the same set phrase, so you can't analyze it and translate just the word "даже" in isolation.

I would translate it this way:

> Even though the family came to terms with the situation — and quite quickly, too,...

Comment: Очень даже is stll in use and is not similar to "too". Otherwise it is OK only you should attribute the quotes properly.

Answer (score -2):

In this case, "even" is the proper translation.